# Why do several of the 2016 Star Wars sets include stands for the minifigs?

Tags: sets, minifigures, star-wars

I've noticed that several of the new Star Wars sets include stands for the minifigs. For example Droid Escape Pod (75136):

[image: 75136]

What is the purpose of these? I don't see how they add play or display value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The stands you see aren't actually part of the set. They're there to make it easier to photograph the minifigs, and get photoshopped out in the final version of the set pictures.

Comment: It looks like LEGO forgot to remove them on their own [shop listing](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Droid-Escape-Pod-75136?fromListing=listing). I couldn't find those stands used in any of the Youtube video reviews of this particular set.

Comment: How do you know this? Or are you just guessing?

Comment: I am mostly guessing, but my answer was based on [some of the discussion on Brickset](http://brickset.com/article/17072/first-batch-of-2016-sets-revealed) when the first bunch of Force Awakens sets were revealed. The fact that a lot of the pictures with stands have since been replaced with versions without the stands seems to confirm the theory.